# Integrability of the Stopping Time in a Random Walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Supposed the following: $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ independent random variable adapted to the $\sigma X_n$ $\forall n$. Consider that: 
$$P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2} $$
and that $X_0=a$ with $1\leq a\leq K-1$.
Now define $S_n=\sum^n_{i=0} X_i$ and
$$\tau=\min\left[n\in N: S_n=0\,or\, S_n=K \right]$$
How can I show that $\tau$ is integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $$M_n := S_n^2-\frac{n}{2}$$ is a martingale.
2. Apply the optional stopping theorem to show that $(M_{n \wedge \tau})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale; in particular, $$\mathbb{E}(S_{n \wedge \tau}^2) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}(n \wedge \tau).$$
3. Show that $|S_{n \wedge \tau}| \leq K$. Use the dominated convergence theorem and the monotone convergence theorem to show that $$\mathbb{E}(S_{\tau}^2) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}(\tau).$$
4. Since $\mathbb{E}(S_{\tau}^2) \leq K^2$, this proves that $\tau$ is integrable.

Comment: Apologies - I know you wrote this answer a long time ago - am I right in thinking that this argument assumes already that $\tau$ is almost surely finite, in order to have that $n\wedge\tau\to\tau$ (and similarly for the LHS term)?